# Xpath 1.0 get previous element value which is not static position

Tags: xpath

My html structure as below

```
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="active"></div>
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="active"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="active"></div>
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <h2>Title 4</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div></div>
    <div class="active"></div>
    <div></div>
```

I would like to get previous first h2's value according to divs which has got **active** class

My xpath descendants axes for selecting nodes as below

```
//div[contains(@class, 'active')]
```

I have tried **ancestor** and **preceding** axes of Xpath but not get right result

is this possible with Xpath 1.0

**Note:** I can use only Xpath version 1.0

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath expression:

```
//div[@class='active']/preceding-sibling::h2[1]
```

which can be read as

> "Select the first `<h2>` element before every active `<div>` element."

should do the trick for you.

Comment: 2 cents: In this case it will be more correct to use the 'preceding-sibling' instead of 'preceding'.

Answer (score 0):

I also vote for the solution suggested by @Slanec - it is good and simple.

But if you want to make sure you are searching for an element within a particular range of elements, you can use an extended XPath:

```
//div[(preceding-sibling::h2 and following-sibling::h2) 
       or preceding-sibling::h2[not(following-sibling::h2)]]
     [@class='active']
     /preceding-sibling::h2[1]
```

It is just the same, except for here 'div' is searched within the range between 2 'h2' elements (or after the 'h2' in case there is no more 'h2' elements on the page).