# End of document in XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I was trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20713008/2724688) question and got stuck when it was necessary to detect the end of HTML document using XPath.

The HTML is:

```
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="active"></div>
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="active"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="active"></div>
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <h2>Title 4</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div></div>
    <div class="active"></div>
    <div></div>
```

My XPath at that point was

```
//h2[following-sibling::div[@class='active'][(preceding-sibling::h2 and following-sibling::h2)]]
```

But it wound not detect the 'Title 4', since there is no 'following-sibling::h2' for the last 'div'. There is only the end of document that I was unable to detect using XPath.

I needed to handle the case when the 'div' is between the 'h2' and the end.

Playing with 'preceding-sibling::h2[position()=last()]' did not help.

Is there a way to define the end of document using XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, since you are trying to find an `h2` in your XPath example, you're looking for the `h2` which is not followed by another `h2`. Given what you gave us, this would do it:

```
//h2[not(following-sibling::h2)]
```

#### "End of Document" in XPath

What could the end of an XPath document be? XPath sees a document as a tree of nodes. Where's the "end of document" in this tree? It really depends on the application. Let's say I have a document like this:

```
<foo>
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <p>A second one</p>
</foo>
```

and in my application I wish to add some hash of the contents of all the paragraphs at the "end of the document". In this case I mean "after the last closing tag". So I'd end up with something like this, with the last line being the hash:

```
<foo>
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <p>A second one</p>
</foo>
1010DEADBEEF1010
```

Now the resulting document won't be conforming XML or HTML but that's fine in my application. With XPath there's no way to say "after the last closing tag". What I *can* do is tell XPath to get the root node and then have something else serialize this node (this is the process that would output the opening and closing tags), and have this something else add my hash after it. (XPath could also be used to select all paragraphs to build the hash).

Different, scenario. I have a document like the one above, but this time I want to add a copyright blurb at the "end of the document." I want the result to be well-formed XML. This time when I say "end of the document" I mean after the "last child of the top level element" so that the final result is this:

```
<foo>
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <p>A second one</p>
  <p>Copyright 2013 Widgets Incorporated</p>
</foo>
```

This time around I can XPath to select the last child of the root element, and then use something else to modify the document so that a paragraph is added after that last child. (XSLT would be a prime example of the kind of tool I'd use to do this, since XSLT uses XPath to match nodes.)

I hope I've shown that "end of document" is an application-specific term that does not have a unique equivalent in the data model used by XPath.

Comment: Thanks @Louis, your answer helped me write a working XPath for that particular HTML.

But it does not answer my initial question about the syntax for the end of document in XPath.

Comment: "End of document" does not translate to a specific XPath concept. I'm busy now but I'll try to come back with an explanation when I'm free (if someone does not get to it before I do).

Answer (score 0):

XPath finds nodes in a tree. The 'end of document' is not represented by a node in the tree , so there is nothing there to find.